# Unmet dependencies upon installing libvirt* and virt-manager after distribution upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies, update-manager

I have been doing an upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to 20.04, then 20.10.
Now, I need to install `virt-manager`, which I'm sure has a package supported on Ubuntu 20.10.
When I try to install it using `sudo apt-get install virt-manager`, I get unmet dependencies problems stating that packages cannot be installed.

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libvirt-glib-1.0-0 : Depends: libvirt0 (>= 1.2.8~rc2) but it is not installable
 python3-libvirt : Depends: libvirt0 (>= 6.0.0-0ubuntu5) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: libvirt-daemon but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My guess is that I have old package making conflicts with those, but that would not make sense due to displayed error messages.

I did try `sudo apt-get update`, and this did not change anything.

Trying to install dependencies brings down to this :

```
E: Package 'libvirt0' has no installation candidate
```

Here is the `/etc/apt/resource.list` :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy partner
```

I do not know why some packages cannot be installed while I should be able to install them.
Does anyone faced this issue already? Am I missing something?

Also, I could not find any related question around here mentioning this kind of stuff happening after a distribution upgrade; although I am aware that unmet dependencies questions are many.

Comment: Downloading libvirt0 deb package from ubuntu's website and installing it made it work, but it is clear that there is still a problem in packages list.

Comment: Sadly, Ubuntu 20.10 is end of life as of today - you should consider upgrading to 21.04 or back to 20.04